What exactly is meant by ' horn' in Psalm 75:5?
We read in Psalm 75:5 with the title : For the director of music. To the tune of “Do Not Destroy.” A psalm of Asaph. A song.

1 We praise you, God,
we praise you, for your Name is near;

people tell of your wonderful deeds.

2 You say, “I choose the appointed time;
it is I who judge with equity.

3 When the earth and all its people quake,
it is I who hold its pillars firm.[b]

4 To the arrogant I say, ‘Boast no more,’
and to the wicked, ‘Do not lift up your horns.[c]

5 Do not lift your horns against heaven;
do not speak so defiantly.’”.


There are different opinions as to whom the Psalm is addressed. When it comes to Verse 5, the word 'horn' , in the language of music, could be read as the wind instrument made of animal horn. If otherwise, it could be seen as a Metaphor for arrogance. My question is: what exactly is meant by ' horn' in Psalm 75:5 ?

The Hebrew word for horn - as a musical instrument - is shophar. It refers to an instrument blown from the lips, as we do today with a cornet, or a trumpet. But in the days of the Old Testament, it was a literal horn of an animal, very long and loud when blown. The Israelites used it in temple worship and/or in war. It did not have a range of many notes; more like a constant blast.
The word shophar is not in Psalm 75:5. The word qeren is used. Psalm 75 is a worship song extolling God. It also speaks of God as the judge of all the Earth, and the proud, stiff-necked ones who symbolically lift up their horn of opposition against God and his people will drink the dregs of his wrathful judgment.
Just think of a rhinoceros about to charge towards that which it will attack. It likely raises its horned head up and down, stamping a front leg on the ground, just before it charges. Then the head has the horn aimed at killing anything in front of it, and to toss it aside. The wicked are viewed by God as proud antagonists, against him and his people, who want to maim and destroy his people (for they cannot get to him!) This seems to be the meaning in Psalm 75, I would suggest.

קֶרֶן qeren horn (feminine) Genesis 22:13 caught in a thicket hy his horns. Up-voted +1. Exodus 29:12. the horns of the altar. Its association is submission (of a feminine kind, as it were) and sacrifice. The Head is held by thorns.

The OP has quoted from the NIV which has a footnote against the word "horns" in V4, V5 & V10 as follows:

Horns here symbolize strength; also in verses 5 and 10.

This appears to be the meaning of the metaphor throughout the psalms (and much of the Bible).
In this psalm, the horns are those of the wicked who are advised not to lift up their horns to heaven.  By contrast in V10 (in precise contradistinction to the wicked), the horns of the righteous will be lifted up by God.
The Cambridge commentary suggests this:

Lift not up the horn  A metaphor, derived from animals tossing their heads, to denote overweening, defiant self-consciousness of
strength.

Benson is even more descriptive:

Lift not up your horn, &c. — Do not carry yourselves with pride and arrogance, boasting of your own strength; or with scorn and
contempt toward me or any others of God’s people. It is a metaphor
taken from untamed oxen, which will not bow their heads to receive the
yoke, but lift up their heads and horns to avoid it.

